# Is there an API or similar way to find out how busy a location is?

Tags: google-maps

I'm looking at building an app that uses how busy a location is currently as an input for a model. I found this library: https://github.com/m-wrzr/populartimes, but it relies on data scraping Google's data which goes against Google's ToS. I've also tried contacting https://besttime.app/, but it sounds like they're also going against Google's ToS at the moment. So is there another api or method that doesn't break some ToS?